# HTML Horizontal Nav Centre

Tags: html, css, center, nav

I'm fairly new to CSS/HTML and am trying to make a horizontal nav with a dropdown menu. I have made the nav but I am having trouble getting it centred on the page.

```css
#NavigationTop ul{
  list-style: none;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding-right: 1px;
  width: 1075px;
}

#NavigationTop ul a{
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:15px;
  padding:0 15px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#NavigationTop ul li{
  background-color: #343434;
  width: 215px;
  height: 50px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#NavigationTop ul li:hover{
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
#NavigationTop ul li a:visited{
  color: #ffffff
}

#NavigationTop ul ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
}

#NavigationTop ul ul li{
  float:none;
  width:215px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

#NavigationTop ul li:hover > ul{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="NavigationTop">
  <div id="main-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="bio/index.html">BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
      <li><a href="discography/index.html" class="disco">DISCOGRAPHY</a></li>
      <li><a href="media/index.html">MEDIA</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Audio</a>
          <li><a href="#">Video</a>
          <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact/index.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I'm sure there are many errors, but what could I do to make it centred? Also is it possible to have the nav hide the overflow from the main ul and still show the drop-down menu? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change only this:

```
#NavigationTop ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-right: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
}

div#main-nav {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to make a div center or any html element. you need a container( eg. div or ul or any other) and place the html element inside that container and give specific **width** to that container with property **margin: 0 auto** . 
By specifying width, your content will not spread across the viewport(brower screen) and when you specify **Margin**, in shorthand notion( 0 auto ) means **0** will hold the margin for **Top & Bottom** while **auto** will hold **Left & Right** automatically by browser.

Then whatever you will place that container, you can use Floating easily so that your design looks perfect.

Remove the width from **#NavigationTop ul**

Add specific width till your menu not breaking then add that on **#main-nav**

```
#main-nav{
    width: 1120px; //in your design case i found it this in px. 
    margin: 0 auto;
}


#NavigationTop ul{
    list-style: none;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-right: 1px;
}
```

```css
 #main-nav{
        width: 1120px; //in your design case i found it this in px. 
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
#NavigationTop ul{
  list-style: none;
 position:relative;
 margin:0 auto;
 padding-right: 1px;
}

#NavigationTop ul a{
 color:#ffffff;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:700;
 font-size:15px;
 padding:0 15px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#NavigationTop ul li{
    background-color: #343434;
    width: 215px;
    height: 50px;
 position:relative;
 float: left;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#NavigationTop ul li:hover{
    background-color: lightseagreen;
}
#NavigationTop ul li a:visited{
    color: #ffffff
}

#NavigationTop ul ul{
    display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}

#NavigationTop ul ul li{
    float:none;
    width:215px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

#NavigationTop ul li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="NavigationTop">
 <div id="main-nav">
 <ul>
     <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
     <li><a href="bio/index.html">BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
  <li><a href="discography/index.html" class="disco">DISCOGRAPHY</a></li>
  <li><a href="media/index.html">MEDIA</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Audio</a>
    <li><a href="#">Video</a>
    <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
  </ul></li>
     <li><a href="contact/index.html">CONTACT</a></li>
 </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `#NavigationTop ul` class remove `padding-left:0` because by default `ul` takes padding and the default seems to be padding-left:40px for `ul`.

```css
#NavigationTop ul{
  list-style: none;
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding-right: 1px;
  width: 1075px;
  overflow:auto;
  padding-left:0;
}

#NavigationTop ul a{
  color:#ffffff;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:15px;
  padding:0 15px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#NavigationTop ul li{
  background-color: #343434;
  width: 215px;
  height: 50px;
  position:relative;
  float: left;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#NavigationTop ul li:hover{
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
#NavigationTop ul li a:visited{
  color: #ffffff
}

#NavigationTop ul ul{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
}

#NavigationTop ul ul li{
  float:none;
  width:215px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

#NavigationTop ul li:hover > ul{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="NavigationTop">
  <div id="main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="bio/index.html">BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
    <li><a href="discography/index.html" class="disco">DISCOGRAPHY</a></li>
    <li><a href="media/index.html">MEDIA</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Audio</a>
        <li><a href="#">Video</a>
        <li><a href="#">Photos</a>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact/index.html">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one https://jsfiddle.net/mnd1b51y/1/

```
#NavigationTop ul li { position: relative;}
#NavigationTop ul li:hover > ul {
    left: 0;
    max-width: 210px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 51px;
}
```